Centralizer of maximal normal nilpotent subgroups
Suppose $G$ is a finite solvable group, and $F$ is the product of all its normal nilpotent subgroups. I need to prove $C_G(F)\subset F$.
My idea: Pick the derived series $G\supset G' \supset\cdots\supset G^{(n)}=1$ and  prove inductively $ C_G(F)\cap G^{(k)}\subset F$. So suppose it's true for $k+1$ and pick any $g\in G^{(k)}\cap C_G(F)$, then for any $h\in G^{(k)}\cap C_G(F)$, (note $C_G(F)$ is normal since $F$ is normal)
$$ghg^{-1}h^{-1}\in G^{(k+1)}\cap C_G(F)\subset F.$$
But then I don't know how to proceed.

Here's another approach, from Isaacs's Algebra. First prove that if $H$ is solvable and non-Abelian, then $Z(H)<F(H)$ [strict containment]. Now consider $C=C_G(F(G))$, in two cases: $C$ is Abelian or non-Abelian. The first case is easy, and the second case can't happen because $$ C\cap F(G) \le Z(C) \le F(C) \le C\cap F(G) $$

You need to use solvability in a different way: write $F=Fit(G)$ and $C=C_G(F) \lhd G$. Assume that the theorem does not hold, so $F \lneqq CF$. Then $CF/F$ is a non-trivial normal subgroup of $G/F$, and hence contains a (non-trivial) minimal normal subgroup $M/F$ of $G/F$. Now we use solvability: it implies that $M/F$ is abelian, so $M' \subseteq F \subsetneq M \subseteq CF$. Observe that $(M \cap C)F=M$ (use Dedekind’s Modular Law). On the other hand, $M \cap C \lhd G$ and $M \cap C$ is nilpotent: $\gamma_3(M \cap C)=[M \cap C, M\cap C, M\cap C] \leq [M',C] \leq [F,C]=1$. Hence $M \cap C \subseteq F$, yielding $(M \cap C)F=F$, but we already observed that $(M \cap C)F=M$. This gives the contradiction $F=M$. $\square$

That's great. So the nilpotence is not necessary here?

Yes it is, $M \cap C$ is normal in $G$ and nilpotent of class 2, so this subgroup ends up in $Fit(G)=F$ (since the Fitting subgroup is the product of all nilpotent normal subgroups of $G$), see above.
